# vim default syntax for files with no extension

Tags: vim

How do I set up a default syntax for files that have no extension in vim?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One way would be to add an autocommand to your `.vimrc` for files that don't have the syntax set:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead * if &syntax == '' | set syntax=html | endif
```

Or, you could set the filetype for any file that it's not defined for:

```
filetype plugin on
au BufNewFile,BufRead * if &ft == '' | set ft=html | endif
```

Setting `filetype plugin on` along with the `au` command gives the added benefit of loading HTML plugins if you have any.  This also sets the syntax to "html" as well.

Answer (score 6):

To pick the default syntax for files without an extension, you can create an autocommand that checks if the filename contains a `.`, and if not, switches to the desired syntax:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * if expand('%:t') !~ '\.' | set syntax=perl | endif
```

This one picks `perl` as a default syntax, but you can simply use whichever is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If I remeber it right you can put a file named syntax.vim inside your ~/.vim/syntax folder. This file is used as default syntax highlight source.
If your .vim folder does not exist, you have to create it:

```
mkdir ~/.vim
mkdir ~/.vim/syntax
touch ~/.vim/syntax/syntax.vim
```

Now you can add your default syntax to the syntax.vim file.
For further documentation you can look at the [vim sourceforge page](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Then please be more accurate about your problem in your description.. it's not very descriptive right now.

Comment: Some files have no extensions (suffixes) right? Case in point, html files I work on don't have .html suffixes. They're named like this: file1, file2, etc. Now, I'd like vim to automatically set html syntax when I'm opening those extension-less files. How do I do that?

Comment: @zly: This can be used to do *exactly* what you asked for - you can edit the installed syntax.vim, or copy it into ~/.vim/syntax. This file is sourced when you run `syntax enable`, so it can easily check to see if a filetype was detected, and use a default (e.g. html) syntax if not.

Comment: @Jefromi, I was expecting specifics not guidelines; guess I wasn't specific enough what I was expecting ;-) @Curt Nelson did answer my question tho.