# How to make vim buffer source to R without .R extension

Tags: r, vim, macvim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I make vim do syntax highlighting on C++ headers that don't have extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584580/can-i-make-vim-do-syntax-highlighting-on-c-headers-that-dont-have-extensions)

I'm using the [R.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2104) script to source my .R files from vim to R-GUI using Applescript. However, this will only work if the file I open in vim has the .R extension.

When I open MacVim, the buffer has no extension, so I have to save the file as temp.R before I can use the shortcuts provided by R-vim for sourcing to R-GUI. I am predominantly an R-user, so I would like to make it so that, by default, when MacVim opens, it assumes the filetype is R and I can begin sourcing the buffer immediately.

Is there a way to automatically tell the buffer the filetype is R so that I don't need to write my buffer before sourcing to R?

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that didn't involve typing something into and saving the file before it would allow highlighting and sourcing. Otherwise, I might as well just save the file as foo.R and avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: Try the Vim-R-Plugin http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2628

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the filetype of a buffer using `:set filetype=R` or short `:set ft=R`

Comment: Is there a way to add that to my vimrc to make all new buffers open as filetype=R?

Comment: you can add `autocmd BufEnter * if &filetype == "" | setlocal ft=R | endif` to your vimrc. This will set the filetype for all unknown files to `R`.