# set vim filetype for files with no extension, only

Tags: vim

How do I set up filetype and/or syntax for files that have no extension in vim?

**Note**

This is a duplicate of [vim default syntax for files with no extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2666551/1000282). I'm asking again because no one has answered it properly in my view.

I don't want to know how to set the default syntax for unrecognized file types, I want to know how to set it only for extensionless files.

Comment: If `filetype` can be detected in vim for this file, you can use this following config(sh script for example, `:set filetype?` in vim is `sh`):     `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * if (&ft == "sh") | set noexpandtab tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 | endif`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create an autocommand that checks if the filename contains a `.`, and if not, switches to a given syntax:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * if expand('%:t') !~ '\.' | set syntax=perl | endif
```

This one picks `perl` as a default syntax, but you can simply use whichever is appropriate.

Comment: Using the `expand()` function, one can directly extract the extension from filename.  So, the test can be also written as `expand('%:e') != ''`.

Comment: @ib. No, see my comment at Geoff Reedy's answer. The problem is that dot named files (as .vimrc), will get no %:e too.

Comment: @Chico:  And that is technically correct: Files like `.vimrc` do not have an extension; the leading dot does not make the rest of the name be an extension.

Comment: @Chico:  Well, it depends on definitions we agree on. :-)  Since there is no strict definition of a filename extension accepted on all platforms and file systems, the question should explicitly state that, within the context of the discussion, by "files with no extension" are understood filenames that do not contain a dot.

Comment: This setting is extremely slow altogether with netrw. Changing the evento to BufNewFile fixed for me.

Answer (score 6):

`:help ftdetect` will show the part of the vim documentation about how to write filetype detection scripts.

Here's what I suggest for this case:

Create a file in `~/.vim/ftdetect` named after your filetype, e.g. `myfiletype.vim`.

In this file put

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile * if expand('<afile>:e') == '' | set ft=myfiletype | end
```

This will cause vim to set the filetype for files without any extension to `myfiletype`. If you want it to only be used if no other filetype was detected use `setfiletype myfiletype` instead of `set ft=myfiletype`.

Then create the syntax file `~/.vim/syntax/myfiletype.vim`. This is just a normal vim syntax defintion file, nothing special. If you do not want to create your own filetype, just use the normal filetype in the autocommand instead of myfiletype. For example

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile * if expand('<afile>:e') == '' | set ft=html | end
```

would set the html file type which would load the html syntax file.

Comment: Your solution looked cool because of the '<afile>:e', but when I opened my .vimrc, it was set by this, so I've chosen the grep \. solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
1) Hit escape to make sure you're in normal mode
2) Type ":set syntax=java" (or equivalent language)
3) :set filetype=FILETYPE, where FILETYPE is the filetype.
```

If you're looking to do this automatically, try using the solution from previous answer:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * if expand('%:t') !~ '\.' | set syntax=perl | endif
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I've chosen this for my C++ configuration:

```
let s:reserved = '^NERD_tree\|^GoToFile$'
au BufNewFile,BufRead *
\ if expand('%:e') =~ '^\(h\|hh\|hxx\|hpp\|ii\|ixx\|ipp\|inl\|txx\|tpp\|tpl\|cc\|cxx\|cpp\)$' ||
\    expand('%:t') !~ '\.\|'.s:reserved && expand('%:t') =~ '[a-z]'                            |
\   if &ft != 'cpp'                                                                            |
\     set ft=cpp                                                                               |
\   endif                                                                                      |
\   set syntax=cpp11                                                                           |
\   call CSyntaxAfter()                                                                        |
\ endif
```

Instead of only checking for the lack of `.` in the tail. This avoids several non cpp files from being set like `COMMIT_EDITMSG`, `README`, `GoToFile` from CommandT and `NERD_tree*` from NERD tree.

**EDIT**

I just gave up on this idea.