# Set commentstring for files of unknown extension

Tags: vim

I want to find a way to set my default commentstring to '#' for files of unknown extension. As far as I know, there is no way to do this.

Issuing a `setlocal commentstring=#\ %s` on my .vimrc would overwrite the commentstring of all known files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I came up to the following solution that works great :

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * if &syntax == '' | setlocal commentstring=#\ %s | endif
```

Idea taken from here:

[vim default syntax for files with no extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666551/vim-default-syntax-for-files-with-no-extension)

Comment: True, thanks for that. Edited to add it. I am not sure why I am being downvoted ? Anyone care to explain it to me ?

Comment: Because your Q and A are the same text, so it is not really correct site usage. You post a question in the question, and answers in answers. They dont really mix (it’s not a forum where text can just go everywhere).

Comment: See the [help] and [ask]

Comment: Thanks for the anwer. I edited the Q&A to match the format. I'd appreciate if you could remove the downvote now please?